# Однокоренные слова

Tags: этимология, однокоренные-слова

"Острог" — это тюрьма, "острога" — гарпун для ловли рыбы. Что между ними общего? Хотя с острогой все понятно ("остро оструганная"), а при чем тут тюрьма?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оба слова, по Фасмеру, имеют происхождение от праслав. формы *ostrъ "острый". Слово **острог** сначала толковалось  как "частокол, или палисадник из свай, вверху заостренных" и только потом - как "тюрьма, арестантская, здание, окруженное острогом или стеною, где содержатъ узников, заключенников, тюремный замок." (Даль).
Обращаю внимание на то, что в современном языке корень в этих словах не -остр-, а -острог- (Словообразовательный словарь Тихонова).

Answer (score 1):

В этимологическом словаре есть указание на то, что значение слова "острог" восходит к слову"остръ" (острый) и первичное его значение было "кол, изгородь, частокол", то есть то, что острогано (особенно кол с обязательным острием). Так что соотнести с орудием "острога" вполне можно.

Comment: Так с каким же смыслом больше связано слово _острог_ - острый или строгать? Или эти слова как-то связаны? Ведь "строгание" не всегда приводит к остроте, чаще - к гладкости дерева...

Comment: Вы пишете, что "первично его значение было "кол, изгородь, частокол", то есть то, что ОСТРОГАНО". Отсрогано - от глагола СТРОГАТЬ. А ОСТРОГ - от слова ОСТРЫЙ. Слова "строгать" и "острый" имеют разное происхождение и разные корни.

Comment: Моя логика была такова: острый, потому что остроган

Comment: @виктор1799, это вряд ли. Остроту можно придать и другими способами. а есть и природные острые вещи. Шипы, рыбные кости и т.п.  

И как же Вы видите это преобразование? Куда девалась часть корня (буква Г)?

Comment: Может быть, мои предположения наивны, но острогом могла называться территория, огороженная острыми (остроганными) кольями острием вверх, чтобы узники не могли перелезть через эту изгородь

Answer (score 1):

Может стоит начать просто с понятия: поймал и надежно спрятал (например). Люди в прошлом не имели столь обширный словарный запас, как мы с вами. Скорее всего сначала слово, как и понятие было одно, далее система внесла корректуру в понятия, а слова остались, немного видоизменившись.